# Change numeric array keys into $variable

Tags: php

I was wondering if anyone could help with a conceptual issue I'm having, or if there is a better way. 
Basically I am searching my database for an array of terms through a search bar. 
I have a function that loops through each term and then uses that for a search. It puts everything in an array and returns the array that is then processed into a table. 
The search works fine, I put in the terms and it loops through them pushing the rows into an array. Now because I am pushing into different Arrays, the parent Array I Have has indexed keys, I want to change that to be keys of the terms and in the array there are two other arrays 1 for the number of results and another for the results.

```
// Search index php

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="search">
    <form id= "search" action="searchresults.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="txtsearch" size="30" id="txtsearch">
    <input type="submit" name="srchbtn" id="srchbtn">Search</button>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
//Search PHP

<?php
include_once "iud.php";

$arrayval = array();

if(isset($_POST['txtsearch'])){
    $search=$_POST['txtsearch'];
}else{
    $search = '';
}
$search1 = explode(" ", $search);

array_push($arrayval, $search1);
$combined = array();
foreach ($arrayval as $val){
    $orIndex = checkOr($val);
    if(empty($orIndex)){
        $valcntr = count($val);
        $results = getResults($val);
        print_r($results);
    }
}

function getResults($array){
    include_once "iud.php";
    $db = connectDatabase();
    $totalResults = array();
    $length = count($array);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        $outputDisplay = "";     
        $myrowcount = 0;
        $sql_statement  = "SELECT userid, username, firstname, lastname ";
        //, congroup, cattype, company, position, email, website, phone, mphone, wphone, fax, add1, add2, city, state, zip, country, reference, entrydate, enteredby, notes ";
        $sql_statement .= "FROM userlist ";
        $sql_statement .= "WHERE (firstname LIKE '%$array[$i]%' or lastname LIKE '%$array[$i]%')"; 
        $sql_statement .= "ORDER BY lastname, firstname";
        $sqlResults = selectResults($db, $sql_statement);

        $error_or_rows = $sqlResults['resultNum'];

        if (substr($error_or_rows, 0 , 5) == 'ERROR')
        {
            $outputDisplay .= "<br />Error on DB";
            $outputDisplay .= $error_or_rows;
        } else {

            array_push($totalResults, $sqlResults);
            $arraySize = $error_or_rows;

        }

    }
    return ($totalResults);
}

function buildTable($totalResults){
    include_once "iud.php";
    $outputDisplay = "";
    $outputDisplay .= '<div id="resultstable">';
    $outputDisplay .= '<ul id="results">';
    $myrowcount = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i < count($totalResults); $i++)
    {
        $myrowcount++;
        $contactid = $totalResults[$i]['userid'];
        $firstname = $totalResults[$i]['firstname'];
        $lastname = $totalResults[$i]['lastname'];
        $pcat      = $totalResults[$i]['username'];

        $outputDisplay .= '<li id='.$contactid.' class="indRes" ';
        $outputDisplay .= 'name="'.$contactid.'" >';
        $outputDisplay .= '<span style="font-size:10px;cursor:pointer" onclick="getContactsToForm();">';
        $outputDisplay .= '<h3>'.$firstname.' ' .$lastname. '</h3>';

        $outputDisplay .= '</span>';
        $outputDisplay .= '</li>';
    }
    $outputDisplay .= '</ul>';
    $outputDisplay .= "</div>";

    return $outputDisplay;
}

function checkOr($searchArray){
    if (in_array("OR",$searchArray)){
        $orPos = array_search("OR", $searchArray);
        if (!empty($orPos)){ 
            $surrVal = "";
            $surrVal = --$orPos;
            $orValArray = array();
            array_push($orValArray,$searchArray[$surrVal]);
            $surrVal = $orPos+2;
            array_push($orValArray,$searchArray[$surrVal]);
            return $orValArray;
        }           
    }
}

?>
//common functinos IUD 
<?php

function connectDatabase()
{
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
    if (!$db)
    {
        print "<h1>Unable to Connect to mysqli</h1>";
    }
    $dbname = 'test';
    $btest = mysqli_select_db($db, $dbname);
    if (!$btest)
    {
        print "<h1>Unable to Select the Database</h1>";
    }
    return $db;
}

function selectResults($db, $statement)
{
    $output = "";
    $outputArray = array();

    $db = connectDatabase();

    if ($db)
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $statement);

        if (!$result) {
            $output .= "ERROR";
            $output .= "<br /><font color=red>mysqli No: ".mysqli_errno();
            $output .= "<br />mysqli Error: ".mysqli_error();
            $output .= "<br />SQL Statement: ".$statement;
            $output .= "<br />mysqli Affected Rows: ".mysqli_affected_rows()."</font><br />";

            array_push($outputArray, $output);

        } else {
            $numresults = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            $outputArray['resultNum'] =  $numresults;
            for ($i = 0; $i < $numresults; $i++)
            {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                $outputArray["rowArray"] = $row;
            }
        }
    } else {
        array_push($outputArray, 'ERROR-No DB Connection');
    }
    return $outputArray;
}

function iduResults($db, $statement)
{
    $output = "";
    $outputArray = array();

    $db = connectDatabase();
    if ($db)
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $statement);

        if (!$result) {
            $output .= "ERROR";
            $output .= "<br /><font color=red>mysqli No: ".mysqli_errno();
            $output .= "<br />mysqli Error: ".mysqli_error();
            $output .= "<br />SQL Statement: ".$statement;
            $output .= "<br />mysqli Affected Rows: ".mysqli_affected_rows()."</font><br />";

        } else {
            $output = mysqli_affected_rows();
        }
    } else {
        $output =  'ERROR-No DB Connection';
    }
    return $output;
}

?>
```

My search returns an array that when printed looks like this:

```
Array(
     [0]=>Array
               (
                [resultNum]=>1
                [rowArray]=>Array(
                                  [0]=>1
                                  [userid]=>1
                                    etc
                                     )
                  )
     [1]=>Array
               (
                [resultNum]=>1
                [rowArray]=>Array(
                                  [0]=>2
                                  [userid]=>2
                                    etc
                                     )
                  )
```

I want to make the two outer arrays' keys `[0],[1]` into the search terms that are used in the loop through the `getResults($array)` function. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Too much code. Please reduce your code to the part that is relevant to the particular question you have. You could just provide a sample input array, and desired output for that sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
array_push($totalResults, $sqlResults);
```

to:

```
$totalResults[$array[$i]] = $sqlResults;
```

to make it an associative array instead of an indexed array.

P.S. you should learn to use `foreach` to loop over array elements, and use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

Also, `selectResults()` is only returning the last row of the query. It should be:

```
   } else {
        $numresults = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $outputArray['resultNum'] =  $numresults;
        $outputArray['rowArray'] = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numresults; $i++)
        {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            array_push($outputArray["rowArray"], $row);
        }
```

so that it returns all the rows instead of overwriting `rowArray` each time through the loop.

Comment: But when I do not use the array_push function and return the array at the end of the function getResults() it only gives me the result for the last term.

Comment: Yes I usually try to use foreach, but I wanted the counter to try something out so I will change that once I get the search working. As for prepared statements I have the actual program using them but I re-wrote this shorter one and didn’t use prepared statements for now.

Comment: What changed between the first and third comments?

Comment: Well you answered my question so I ranked it up, since each array is unique its returning the results correctly, but when there is more than one result it only pushes the last array.

Comment: That problem is in `selectResults()`, it's only putting the last row in `$outputArray["rowArray"]`, instead of using `array_push()`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: OK that worked beautifully. I have one more question - but a quick update, it didnt work as is, with ['rowArray']; I had to change that to ['rowResults']

Comment: `rowArray` is what you called it in your function, so I copied that, but I made a mistake on the new line.

Comment: the result  Array ( 
[pari] => Array ( 
[resultNum] => 1 [rowResults] => Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [userid] => 1 [1] => pb1646a [username] => pb1646a [2] => Pari [firstname] => Pari [3] => Baker [lastname] => Baker ) ) ) 
[baker] => Array ( [resultNum] => 2 [rowResults] => Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
[0] => 2 [userid] => 2 [1] => rhl [username] => rhl [2] => Anis [firstname] => Anis [3] => Baker [lastname] => Baker ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [userid] => 1 [1] => pb1646a [username] => pb1646a [2] => Pari [firstname] => Pari [3] => Baker [lastname] => Baker ) ) ) 

)

Comment: can I compare [pari] and [baker]

Comment: Compare `$totalResults['pari']` with `$totalResults['baker']`

Comment: yea but that would only work assuming I know that there are two variables pari and baker, I could use $result[$val[$i]]]; in a foreach loop but then it would need to dynamically change depending on whether  there are three or four terms in the search bar.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to be able to compare every row with every other row?

Comment: Yes I want to extract the duplicates that coincide with each search term

Comment: anyhow its okay, I'll find another way. Thanks for your help

Comment: `foreach ($totalResults as $i => $result1) { foreach ($totalResults as $j => $result2) { if ($i < $j) { // code to compare $result1 and $result2 }}`